# wifi driver for MSI GP62MVR

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, laptop

I've installed ubuntu on my laptop (the MSI GP62MVR) and I cannot connect through wifi, I can connect by lan but this creates issues for when I do not have an ethernet cable.

My question is simply how can I fix this problem and connect with wifi.

Some handy information:

> $ uname -a

```
Linux Xodad3 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> $ ifconfig -a

```
    br-5b8bfe8f3280 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:73:7e:da:13  
              inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    br-94d77fda732c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:a6:56:35:fd  
              inet addr:172.21.0.1  Bcast:172.21.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::42:a6ff:fe56:35fd/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:168 (168.0 B)

    br-c76e1f5c25d6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:11:b1:64:30  
              inet addr:172.22.0.1  Bcast:172.22.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::42:11ff:feb1:6430/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:264982 (264.9 KB)

    br-cc457eb3c43f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:06:75:93:78  
              inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    br-de30f515277c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ad:1b:63:03  
              inet addr:172.23.0.1  Bcast:172.23.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::42:adff:fe1b:6303/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:2568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:701568 (701.5 KB)  TX bytes:574510 (574.5 KB)

    br-f412d79509fc Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0c:c4:82:9c  
              inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:172.19.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:cd:62:fc:f4  
              inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:81:49:8e  
              inet addr:192.168.121.135  Bcast:192.168.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe81:498e/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:2677690 errors:0 dropped:5333 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:949363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:1645974202 (1.6 GB)  TX bytes:103317215 (103.3 MB)
              Interrupt:19 

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:31670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:31670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
              RX bytes:269116757 (269.1 MB)  TX bytes:269116757 (269.1 MB)

    veth121b824 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:4a:a8:ff:34:27  
              inet6 addr: fe80::504a:a8ff:feff:3427/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:2119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:3593 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:746420 (746.4 KB)  TX bytes:989588 (989.5 KB)

    veth1a940ba Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:b4:1a:8a:f9:4f  
              inet6 addr: fe80::20b4:1aff:fe8a:f94f/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:284694 (284.6 KB)

    veth55102e9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:95:02:52:fc:4b  
              inet6 addr: fe80::a895:2ff:fe52:fc4b/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:284436 (284.4 KB)

    veth5afa8a0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:21:d9:76:04:80  
              inet6 addr: fe80::21:d9ff:fe76:480/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:4486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:6439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:3584839 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:960057 (960.0 KB)

    vethac2eafc Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ba:6d:88:a0:f3:ac  
              inet6 addr: fe80::b86d:88ff:fea0:f3ac/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:5648 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:6711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:1082246 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:3846044 (3.8 MB)

    vethc96bb38 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7e:5c:2e:5f:a6:19  
              inet6 addr: fe80::7c5c:2eff:fe5f:a619/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:191 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:20432 (20.4 KB)  TX bytes:374340 (374.3 KB)

    wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:ef:18:f0:84:2b  
              inet addr:192.168.121.35  Bcast:192.168.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::e415:4e6e:ebe2:c284/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:339803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:53340660 (53.3 MB)  TX bytes:200097 (200.0 KB)
```

> $ sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 81
       serial: 84:ef:18:f0:84:2b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-104-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.121.35 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:140 memory:df300000-df301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 4c:cc:6a:81:49:8e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.121.135 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:141 memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: vethc96bb38
       serial: 7e:5c:2e:5f:a6:19
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: veth5afa8a0
       serial: 02:21:d9:76:04:80
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: veth1a940ba
       serial: 22:b4:1a:8a:f9:4f
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: veth55102e9
       serial: aa:95:02:52:fc:4b
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: veth121b824
       serial: 52:4a:a8:ff:34:27
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: vethac2eafc
       serial: ba:6d:88:a0:f3:ac
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

> $ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c20 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

let me know if more information is necessary. Then I'll provide it as soon as I can

Comment: See here: https://codeyarns.com/2017/02/04/how-to-make-intel-wireless-ac-3165-work-in-ubuntu/ - you need to install the latest HWE (Hardware Enablement) kernel as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Comment: @JonasCz goosmaster has a driver and the interface even has an IP address, so why is a kernel needed?

Comment: @JonasCz sadly this didn't work for me, any other suggestions?